# Представление вектора в виде четырехмерного массива

Tags: c++, массивы, вектор

Здравствуйте!

Программа осуществляет чтение данных из файла, содержащего 7440 строк. Каждая строка записывается в вектор.

Каким образом можно перенести элементы этого вектора в четырехмерный массив?

```
void myClass::conversion()
{
   int ix, iy,iz;
   double* myarray=&myvec[0]; 
   typedef double MyType[26][2][40][5];
   for(int i=0 ;i<26;++i)
   {
      for(int j=0; j<2; ++j)
      {
         for(int k=0;k<40; ++k)
         {
            if(!index(i, j ,k, iz,  ix,  iy))continue; //проверяем индексы
            for(int l=0; l<5; ++l)
            {
               cout<<reinterpret_cast<MyType &>(*myarray)[0][j][k][l]<<endl;
            }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Печать выдает абсолютно другие значения, они присутствуют в файле, но индексация не совпадает, хотя аналогичный тест для двумерного массива работал. Помимо `reinterpret_cast`, какие еще бывают решения подобных задач?

Comment: Не очевидно, что такое `myvec` - `vector<double>`? и неизвестно, правильно вы записываете считанные из файла данные - может, вы там путаете что-то в индексах...

Comment: @Harry Тип у вектора также `double`, заполнение выполняется корректно, т.к. значение для индекса n соответствует значению из файла для строки n+1

Answer (score 1):

Может, дело просто в

```
[0][j][k][l]
```

вместо

```
[i][j][k][l]
```

?

Comment: Хорошее замечание, но почему-то если заменить `[0]` на `[i]`, то печать выдает всякий мусор в виде нулей и отрицательных чисел.

Comment: Тогда дайте код, как вы *записываете* данные. Вывод по вашему принципу вполне работоспособен (см., например, http://ideone.com/I5rrWk ). Лучше всего - дайте минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve